# What kind of DB Foursquare using?

Tags: database, google-maps, maps, foursquare

what kind of db foursquare is using?
I don't mean: MySQL, Oracle, or whatever, I mean:
Where they get the venue?
From google maps?

Comment: Questions about what technology a particular company is using at any given time are too localized, unless you want to talk about how to implement a similar technology in your own application.

Comment: I need to implement a similar thing on my app.
What I can do?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, 4SQ is using [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) and [Geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation)

I don't know what you're using for technology, but I've written a pretty sweet "lat/lon" locator that works with Google maps and Bing maps.  It's in VB.NET and outputs the Latitude and Longitude as JSON.

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Namespace Utilities.Apis
    Public NotInheritable Class Geolocation
        ''# This is the object that we are going to store the latitude and
        ''# longitude contained in the API response.
        Private coordinates As Coordinates
        Public Sub New()
            coordinates = New Coordinates
        End Sub

        Private Const googleUrl As String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false"
        Private Const bingUrl As String = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine={0}&key={1}&CountryRegion={2}"
        Private Const bingKey As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        Public Enum apiProvider
            Google = 1
            Bing = 2
        End Enum

        ''''# <summary>
        ''''# Gets the Latitude and Longitude of an address using either Bing or Google Geolocation
        ''''# </summary>
        ''''# <param name="Provider">ENUM apiProvider [Bing] or [Google]</param>
        ''''# <param name="Address">The address of the coordinates you'd like to locate</param>
        ''''# <param name="countryCode">Bing doesn't play nice outside the US without this. use "CA" for Canada</param>
        ''''# <returns>A JSON string using "Latitude" and "Longitude" from the Coordinates class</returns>
        Public Function GetLatLon(ByVal Provider As Integer,
                                  ByVal Address As String,
                                  Optional ByVal CountryCode As String = "CA") As String

            ''# If there happens to be some strange behavior with the placeholder,
            ''# we want to ensure that the "demo" content is not submitted to the
            ''# api.
            If Address = "6789 university drive" Then
                Return Nothing
            End If

            Address = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Address)

            Dim url As String
            Dim responseType As Type
            If Provider = apiProvider.Bing Then
                url = String.Format(bingUrl, Address, bingKey, CountryCode)
                responseType = GetType(BingResponse)
            ElseIf Provider = apiProvider.Google Then
                url = String.Format(googleUrl, Address)
                responseType = GetType(GoogleResponse)
            Else
                ''# If for some reason, the apiResponse is NOT Google or Bing,
                ''# then we want to return Google anyways.
                url = String.Format(googleUrl, Address)
            End If

            ''# Initiate the Http Web Request to the respective provider
            Dim request = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

            ''# Deflate the compressed (gzip'd) response
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate")
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate

            ''# Serialize the response into it's respective Data Contract
            Dim serializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(responseType)

            ''# Because the JSON Response from Google and Bing are drastically
            ''# different, we need to consume the response a little differently
            ''# for each API.  I'd like to figure out a way to shrink this a
            ''# little more, but at the same time, it's working. So I'm going to
            ''# leave it alone for now [Nov 28,2010]


            ''# Here we're handling the Bing Provider
            If Provider = apiProvider.Bing Then
                Dim res = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()), BingResponse)
                Dim resources As BingResponse.ResourceSet.Resource = res.resourceSets(0).resources(0)
                Dim point = resources.point
                With coordinates
                    .latitude = point.coordinates(0)
                    .longitude = point.coordinates(1)
                End With


                ''# Here we're handling the Google Provider
            ElseIf Provider = apiProvider.Google Then
                Dim res = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()), GoogleResponse)
                Dim resources As GoogleResponse.Result = res.results(0)
                Dim point = resources.geometry.location
                With coordinates
                    .latitude = point.lat
                    .longitude = point.lng
                End With
            End If

            ''# Serialize the coordinates and return the string
            Dim jsonSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer
            Return jsonSerializer.Serialize(coordinates)
        End Function
    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class BingResponse
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property resourceSets() As ResourceSet()
        <DataContract()>
        Public Class ResourceSet
            <DataMember()>
            Public Property resources() As Resource()
            <DataContract([Namespace]:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1", name:="Location")>
            Public Class Resource
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property point() As m_Point
                <DataContract()>
                Public Class m_Point
                    <DataMember()>
                    Public Property coordinates() As String()
                End Class
            End Class
        End Class
    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class GoogleResponse
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property results() As Result()
        <DataContract()>
        Public Class Result
            <DataMember()>
            Public Property geometry As m_Geometry
            <DataContract()>
            Public Class m_Geometry
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property location As m_location
                <DataContract()>
                Public Class m_location
                    <DataMember()>
                    Public Property lat As String
                    <DataMember()>
                    Public Property lng As String
                End Class
            End Class
        End Class

    End Class
End Namespace
```

and here's how easy it is to call it.

```
Geolocate.GetLatLon(Utilities.Apis.Geolocation.apiProvider.Google, "1234 Some Funky Street, Home Town, MI", "US")
```

So in the end, they use the combination of their own Geolocating, as well as the information that "can" be submitted by twitter or by the end users mobile device (the iPhone for example asks if you want to allow it to send location information).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for since your question is vague. But I gave it a shot. You can use the same concept in whatever language you like.

Answer (score 0):

They rely on users to enter new locations.  They may have seeded it at some point with an import.